# tf.nn.embedding_lookup() with SparseTensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I create a list of SparseTensors and am trying to use them in calculation. When I try to access them using tf.nn.embedding_lookup, it says `TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.SparseTensor object at 0x1097a7e80>`

Can I use SparseTensors as embeddings? Is there a way to get around this issue?

Thanks in advance